# Memory Management objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Hi i am new into `Objective-c`.
Please guide me how to release memory of instance variable and retained property.
Here i want to release retained property.
Do we release properties?

```
  @interface VAViewController ()
  @property(nonatomic, retain)NSMutableDictionary *starDict;
  @end
  @implementation VAViewController
  @synthesize starDict = _starDict;

  -(void)setDictName
  {
     [self.starDict setValue:@"maddt" forKey:@"dictName"];
  }
  -(void)dealloc
  {
     [_starDict release];
     [super dealloc];
  }
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      _starDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

      [self setDictName];
  }
 @end
```

Comment: your code is correct. it is not clear what you are asking...

Comment: i released ivar(_starDict) in dealloc but i did not released property self.starDict.Is it necessary to release retained property.

Answer (score 1):

In your init method modify :

```
_name = [@"" retain];
```

by

```
_name = @"";
```

But, ARC appear with iOS 5 and now we are in iOS 7. If you are new with Objective-C use ARC because Apple will release your object better like you can do.

Comment: I too would suggest to use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC). It will automatically 'free' memory when it is no longer being referenced. So you don't totally have to worry about memory management. You still have to allocate objects, but retain and release happens automatically

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

> Here i want to release retained property. Do we release properties?

keep in mind that `self.starDict` is just a handy way to access the ivar, not a separate object. actually, a property is just a couple of setter and getter methods associated to some storage (the ivar).

if you release the ivar, you are done. if you set the property to nil, this will also release the ivar (and set it to nil) and you are done all the same.

from a different viewpoint, consider the following cases:

```
1.    [_starDict release]; _starDict = nil;

2.    self.starDict = nil;
```

they are exactly the same (if your property is declared as `retain`), so you do either one. you can of course do both, but since doing either 1 or 2 has the effect of niling your ivar/property, then doing the other operation has no effect whatsoever.

(btw, I prefer niling the property, because is more compact and readable.)

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

again, on the merits of using the property-based syntax to do the release, consider what you do in `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  _starDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

  [self setDictName];
}
```

Now, this will leak memory in case `viewDidLoad` is called twice (this could happen in older versions of the iOS SDK, following a `viewDidUnload` call).

So, what you should do is always releasing your object before assigning to the ivar again:

```
[_starDict release]; _starDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

or:

```
self.starDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init] autorelease];
```

Comment: Yes this helped me a lot.Does self.starDict = nil leaks memory.

Comment: no, it will not leak memory by itself. see also my edit for more hints. indeed, ensuring that there are no memory leaks is not easy at all, and you need being aware of many cases...

Answer (score 0):

If you use ARC (automatic reference count) in latest Obj C and xcode, you do not need to handle this retain, release things. Just overlook and delcare your var and use that. 
But the program you wrote, you need to disable ARC in xcode, if you are using latest Xodes version 4 or 5.
Also use,

```
if ( self )
{
  self.name = @"";
}
```

in init method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should release properties.
Better way is setting released object to nil;

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    [_object release], _object = nil
    [super dealloc];
}
```

If you want to release property you can use just

```
- (void) dealloc
{
    self.object = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}
```